# I want to use openStreetMap data to render roads in openGL, where should I start?

Tags: opengl, maps, geocoding, openstreetmap

What I have in mind is that user will select the part of world he/she wants to generate roads and retrieve openStreetMap data and use it to render roads in openGL.

On searching the web and experimenting, I thought of this approach:

1. get xml file of selected map
2. parse the xml and generate roads by openGL.

But I think this is very naive approach.

Also to experiment a bit I used OSM2WorldViewer to convert the xml file to obj file and imported that as a model in openGL, but this method is cumbersome and takes time

[image: the screenshot]

and I am unfamiliar with OpenStreetMap api and how it can be used in such a project.
Any suggestions, or helpful links how to start this project ?

EDIT: How it ended: [Link to the project wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/3D-mapland)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you think your approach is naive? Either you have the user to provide a self-downloaded XML file or you have to use an API to retrieve one yourself. The latter approach allows you to implement an automatic update mechanism whenever the user pans the map.

Instead of the [main API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) you can use the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) for downloading data. It's faster and more flexible to use, allowing to specify which element types to download (e.g. only roads and buildings) and much more.

You already mentioned [OSM2World](http://osm2world.org/), take a look at its freely available code to see an example implementation of a 3D OpenGL renderer. Or take a look at one of the other [3D renderers](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering#3D_Rendering) for OSM.

Comment: Thanks a million for your reply, it really helps me a lot.           where can I get some tutorials for using these api's in my code ?     I intend to look into the overpass api, sounds much simpler, and will look into OSM2World code too. Keeping question open for some time to see if someone else replies, I thought my question was so weird nobody was answering it... :)

Comment: link of finished project screenshots : https://13ecaeaac30e54bbc97fa56d72a1eb6e88e76f55.googledrive.com/host/0B3_5TE9Dm8zxM3dJRkVOZFNUREE/myWebsite.html#/projects

Comment: Looks great! Is the project open source?

Comment: Nice. If you already have an OSM account you can list your project at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/3D_Development. If you don't have an account I can do that for you if you like.

Comment: Thanks scai, yes the code is available at : https://github.com/Anubha-Banerjee/3d-mapLand , I have updated the code and created an account, was looking into how to edit the wiki page in link you have provided to list the project.